# Miyuki and Kaguya flashbacks - Anything after Ch121 / S03E09?

Tags: kaguya-sama-love-is-war

After [Ch121](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_121) / [S0309](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_33), what chapters show flashbacks of interactions between Kaguya and Miyuki Shirogane before the 1st chapter / episode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Manga spoilers**

Ch 146 (page 10-11)

Ch 147 (page 9-13)

Ch 150 (page 11)

Ch 151 (page 9, 15)

Ch 193 (with Kaguya's POV of repeated flashback)

---

Compiled by Ok-Cod5254 [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Kaguya_sama/comments/wd017l/comment/iifpe3i/?context=3).